# image link not working and ie conditional styles not showing up

Tags: css

So I volunteered to help fix a relative's site. and the code was generated by iweb, so you can imagine it isn't pretty. Anyway I'm having a couple issues, first I put an image in a link and it isn't working: (the link is not being followed).

`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/brackenhollow.stables" style="display:block; z-index:300;"><img src="sidebarbgs_05.png" alt="we're all about horseback riding"/></a>`

Also if you notice inline styles, pretend you don't. The other thing, the hero element on the main page isn't working on i.e. so I tried some i.e. conditional styles which can be found in the head element, but for some reason they aren't being applied.

```
<style type="text/css">
.tinyText{
top: 8px !important;

}
[if IE] #stupidie{
left: -4px !important;
top: 1px !important;

}
</style>
```

Any suggestions? the site can be seen here: www.brackenhollowstables.com

Comment: What about the image in the link isn't working? Does the image not appear? Does the link not work?

Comment: Hi dryden, you can view it on the site. It won't follow the link. Thanks. (it's the facebook button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a format I'm not aware of, but your IE conditionals look incorrectly formatted. Rather than

```
[if IE] #stupidie{
left: -4px !important;
top: 1px !important;

}
```

It should be

```
<!--[if IE]>
#stupidie{
left: -4px !important;
top: 1px !important;
}
<![endif]-->
```

***UPDATE***

The issue with your link not working is due to you z-indexes. You have a whole mess of them throughout the page and it appears that the `#body_layer` div is covering your sidebar. When I remove the `z-index` property from the CSS, it allows you to click on the link. that does break the rest of your page though. The other thing you could do is change the width of `#body_layer` to ~500px. That keeps it from overflowing onto the sidebar and covering your link.

Comment: wow, thanks man.. Let me digest that a second.. Thanks for looking at that, I appretiate it.. I wonder if maybe I could just increase the z-index higher and maybe it would come out on top? Anyway thanks again.

Comment: The z-index is already higher than the other elements so there's something else funky going on here.

Comment: heh yeah man, never seen anything quite like it.. (the whole site that is).

Comment: yeah, that width 500px does the trick. cheers man.. over to filezilla I go.

Answer (score 1):

As for the image, it seems to be missing a `./` in the source url.  As in, it should be:

`<img src="./sidebarbgs_05.png" alt="we're all about horseback riding"/>`

(this for the relative URLs to work)

Comment: Hi blurfus, no the image is displaying, it's just the link in the anchor tag that isn't being followed.

Comment: yeah. I think dryden is on to it here though. Makes some great observations.